# How to clear a DevExpress TimeEdit control in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, time, devexpress

I have a DevExpress TimeEdit control in a WinForms application.
I want it to be cleared when the user clicks the cancel button.

The ID of the TimeEdit control is **makretst**

Here is an image of the control:

[image]

Comment: Is it a DateTimePicker?

Comment: İs it devexpress timeedit object?

Comment: Your image can not be seen. You have to copy paste your code.

Comment: does DateEdit1.EditValue = DBNull.Value work
else does this help? https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/DQ16840/defaulting-the-timeedit-control-to-blank

Comment: yes it is deveexpress time control

Comment: Unfortunately, without being able to see the relevant snippet of your code, any help we are able to give you is extremely limited

Comment: Is the control databound to a source?

Answer (score 0):

Fire Button Click event and add this code :

```
timeEdit1.EditValue = null;
```

or

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeEdit1.EditValue = null;
}
```